# How to get the quartiles of a list of integers

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics

I have a function which I want to find Q1, Q2, and Q3 of a list of ordered integers.

```
intList = [5, 10, 14, 15, 26, 30, 31, 33, 34, 47, 64]

def quartiles(numbers):
    Q1, Q2, Q3 = np.quantile(numbers, [0.25, 0.5, 0.75], axis=0)
    return {
        'Q1': Q1,
        'Q2': Q2,
        'Q3': Q3
    }
```

The function is returning:

```
{'Q1': 14.5, 'Q2': 30.0, 'Q3': 33.5}
```

But the actual Q1, Q2, Q3 are 14, 30, and 34.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [`numpy.quantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) is performing an interpolation. I believe you rather want the nearest point.

You can use the `method='nearest'` parameter (**NB. this requires numpy ≥ 1.22.0**, for previous versions use `interpolation='nearest'` instead):

```
intList = [5, 10, 14, 15, 26, 30, 31, 33, 34, 47, 64,]

def quartiles(numbers):
    Q1, Q2, Q3 = np.quantile(numbers, [0.25, 0.5, 0.75], axis=0, method='nearest')
    return {
        'Q1': Q1,
        'Q2': Q2,
        'Q3': Q3
    }
```

Output: `{'Q1': 14, 'Q2': 30, 'Q3': 34}`